# How to map the value of async functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

`getUserInfo` - a function that receives an array of all users and passes it to the callback function.
`getUsersIds` - Returns an array of user IDs (async function)
`getUserInfo` - Returns user data for the given identifier (async function)

The function must call the callback passed by the first argument and pass an array of user data there.

The order of users in the resulting array must match the order of the IDs in the array from getUsersIds

```
const { getUserInfo, getUsersIds } = db;

function getUsersInfo(onLoad) {
    let res = [];
    getUsersIds(ids => {
        ids.forEach((id, index) => {
            getUserInfo((id, value) => {
                res[index] = value;
                console.log(value);
                if(ids.length === res.length){
                    onLoad(res);
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

data does not match by index. How to do it differently?

Comment: It would be useful to see the output you're getting and what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are firing off all the `getUserInfo` calls at once, and populating the `res` array as those calls resolve, which is not going to be in the same order. You can use `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()` to wait for all to respectively resolve or resolve/reject and then return the results.

You can use

```
function getUsersInfo() {
    return getUsersIds().then(ids => Promise.all(ids.map(getUserInfo)))     
    }
```

...or using `async/await`:

```
async function getUsersInfo() {
    let ids = await getUsersIds();
    let infos = await Promise.all(ids.map(getUserInfo));
    return infos
    }
```

...and then invoke your `onLoad` function like

```
getUsersInfo().then(onLoad);
```